# Pandas/Python - Create new column based on cross reference from other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset with employee information. In this dataset the relevant fields are the EmployeeName column, ID column, and SupervisorName column. I want to create a new column called SupervisorID that gives us the ID of each employee's supervisor.

Input dataframe:

```
EmployeeName   ID SupervisorName
         Jim  123       Brittany
    Brittany  345           Todd
        Todd  456          Grace
```

expected output:

```
EmployeeName   ID SupervisorName  SupID
         Jim  123       Brittany    345
    Brittany  345           Todd    456
```

I am stunted on how to write this efficiently, I have tried using np.where() syntax and .iloc[] but I am new to python and would appreciate any help on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use merge, and merge the `DataFrame` with itself

```
import pandas as pd

data =[{'EmployeeName': 'Jim', 'ID': 123,'SupervisorName': 'Brittany'},
{'EmployeeName': 'Brittany', 'ID': 345,'SupervisorName': 'Todd'},
{'EmployeeName': 'Todd', 'ID': 456,'SupervisorName': 'Grace'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_sup = df[['EmployeeName','ID']]
df_sup= df_sup.rename(columns={'EmployeeName': 'SupervisorName', 'ID': 'SupID'})
df = df.merge(right=df_sup, on='SupervisorName', how='inner')
df
```

output:

```
  EmployeeName   ID SupervisorName  SupID
0          Jim  123       Brittany    345
1     Brittany  345           Todd    456
```

Comment: Thank you Dean! This worked perfectly. I'll definitely remember this trick.

Answer (score -1):

You can set your EmployeeName as key to map to their IDs:

```
df1['SupID'] = df1['SupervisorName'].map(df1.set_index('EmployeeName')['ID'])
df1 = df1.dropna().astype({'SupID': int})
```

output:

```
  EmployeeName   ID SupervisorName  SupID
0          Jim  123       Brittany    345
1     Brittany  345           Todd    456
```